# Update statement in sql doesnt work , microsoft access with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I currently doing the changepassword function in my vb.net project, user can click change password to change their password

But my code doesnt update correctly , it will show "updated" but when i go to my database access table the data still remain the same

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Public Class frmUserDetail
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Private Sub FrmUserDetail_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\phoneOnline.accdb;Persist Security Info=false;")
        loadUserDetail()
        txtUserName.Enabled = False ' set it to false so user cannot do shit with it
    End Sub
    Public Sub loadUserDetail()
        conn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\phoneOnline.accdb;Persist Security Info=false;")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim userName As String = frmMain.lblUserLogin.Text
        'specify name of the user
        Dim search As String = "SELECT * from tblUser WHERE UserName= '" + userName + "'"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(search)
        cmd.Connection = conn
        Dim dtt As New DataTable()
        Dim daa As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        daa.Fill(dtt)
        If dtt.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
            txtUserName.Text = dtt.Rows(0)(0).ToString 'show the userName
            txtUserPassword.Text = dtt.Rows(0)(1).ToString 'show the password of the user 
            txtEmail.Text = (dtt.Rows(0)(2).ToString) 'show user email
        Else
            MsgBox("You are currently login as a guest")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub changePassword()
        If cbChangePassword.Checked Then
            txtChangePassword.Enabled = True
        Else
            txtChangePassword.Enabled = Not (True)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CbChangePassword_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbChangePassword.CheckedChanged
        changePassword()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE tblUser SET UserPassword=@userpass,Email=@email WHERE UserName=@userName;"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql.ToString, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userpass", txtChangePassword.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text) 'pass the time variable from the form 1 to the parameter
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("updated")
        conn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Hide()
        frmMain.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I Expect my database will get updated when i updated it

Comment: Your parameters are out of order (with this provider, parameters are positional, not named). Also, don't use relative paths in the connection string.

Comment: I wish login-in code would not be taught until salting and hashing of passwords is introduced. Passwords should NEVER be stored as plain text. Don't use .AddWithValue. Don't concatenate strings to build sql commands. Always use parameters. Database objects need to be closed and disposed.